# How to distinguish ng-hide true or false whilst parsing url

Tags: vba, excel, html-parsing

I can successfully get innertext of `<td>` tags for both `<table class="specs" ng-hide="false">` and `<table class="specs ng-hide" ng-hide="true">` with this:

```
Set CHRA = aIE.document.getElementsByClassName("specs")(4).getElementsByTagName("td")

For Each Item In CHRA
    Debug.Print Item.innertext
Next
```

These true and false html are from different urls, where one table is hidden and the other is visible to user. For True one, outputs are `CHRA` and `779543-0027`, For False one, outputs are `CHRA` and `715214-0011`:

I don't want to get the result for the false property. Is there any way that I can bypass this?

Here is the rest of the html code (true version is exactly the same except first part is `<table class="specs ng-hide" ng-hide="true">`:

```
<table class="specs" ng-hide="false">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">BOM Info</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>CHRA</td>
                                    <td><span class="ng-binding">715214-0011</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ng-hide="bom.strChra[0]==undefined" id="cpbchra" class="combuy" value="715214-0011" style="display: none;"></td>
                                </tr> 
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in case you are interested:

```
Set CHRA1 = aIE.document.getElementsByClassName("specs ng-hide")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
Set CHRA2 = aIE.document.getElementsByClassName("specs")(4).getElementsByTagName("td")

If CHRA1(1).innertext <> CHRA2(1).innertext Then
    Debug.Print CHRA2(1).innertext
End If
```